# References numbering

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, citing

Latex is numbering my references from the very document beginning including the List of Figures. As a consequence, the first reference to be cited (in the introduction) is already number 5.

How can I set LaTeX to start the counting in introduction only?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a short example code that reproduces the problem. Without this, it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: Well, is not easy because this is for my thesis which is a full document divided in chapters where each is one folder. Then from the main .tex I compile everything.

Comment: You seem to have `\cite` commands in captions, don't you?

Comment: I solved the problem by using the package "notoccite". Had to compile bibtex then full document, and it worked very well! Thanks